# Can't import foreign key in MySQL DB using C#, Visual Studio and MySQL.Data

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, mysql.data

I am getting data from MSSQL DB with Entity Framework using C# and Visual Studio and importing it in MySQL DB using MySQL.Data nuget package and C# and Visual Studio again. If I have data without foreing keys everything is OK and the import is done. Here is the code:

```
var context = new SupermarketsChainEntities();
var measures = context.Measures;
var supermarkets = context.Supermarkets;
var vendors = context.Vendors;
var expenses = context.Expenses;
var products = context.Products;

    String myConn = "server=localhost;Database=supermarkets_chain;uid=root;pwd=;";
    MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(myConn);
    conn.Open();

    //Insert measures
    foreach (var measure in measures)
    {
        String insertQuery = "insert into measures (id, name) values (null, @name)";
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(insertQuery, conn);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", measure.Name);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
```

But when I try to import data in table with one-to-many relationships and foreign keys:

```
foreach (var product in products)
        {
            String insertQuery = "insert into products (id, name, price, measure_id, vendor_id) values (null, @name, @price, @measure_id, @vendor_id)";
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(insertQuery, conn);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", product.Name);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@price", product.Price);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@measure_id", product.Measure);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@vendor_id", product.Vendor);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();      
        }
```

something goes wrong and I get the following exception:

```
Unhandled Exception: MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: Cannot add or update
 a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`supermarkets_chain`.`products`, C
ONSTRAINT `fk_products_measures` FOREIGN KEY (`measure_id`) REFERENCES `measures
` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.ReadPacket()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.GetResult(Int32& affectedRow, Int64& i
nsertedId)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.GetResult(Int32 statementId, Int32& affected
Rows, Int64& insertedId)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.NextResult(Int32 statementId, Boolean force)

   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.NextResult()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior
)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at SqlToMysql.Program.Main(String[] args) in d:\SoftUni\DatabaseApps\Teamwork
\SqlToMysql\SqlToMysql\Program.cs:line 67
```

Can someone help me handle the problem and import the data properly. I am attaching the DB schema [here](http://postimg.org/image/u9h4surx3/).

Comment: have you got add foreign key in entity framework shema ? like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19591513/how-to-add-foreign-key-relationship-in-entity-framework

Comment: I believe so, here is the edmx diagram: [link](http://postimg.org/image/n8q6zqe9j/)

Comment: have you got update your model ?

Comment: What did you mean with update model?

Comment: you add manualy your foreign key in entity framework model or you do an update of your model and the foreign key appeared ?

Comment: I just had the data in MSSQL DB and imported in in Visual Studio with Database first and it automaticaly made all models for me with all the realtions.

Comment: ok and you don't make change on your entity model ?

Comment: Yes i didn't change anything. I am actually getting part of the data in the table products and then i get that exeption. I changed little bit the code - instead of ("@measure_id", product.Measure); i tried: ("@measure_id", product.Measure.Id); because the Measure is the naviagtion property and i tried to get its Id that way but the result is the same.

Comment: hum, the measure_id you want to add exist in your other table ? it's your foreight key right ?

Comment: Yes it is the foreign key for the products table and i get it from the measures table.

Comment: Are you sure you have the right measure id because this error appeared when you want to add data and the id pass doesn't exist

Comment: look at this response [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12966626/mysql-cannot-add-or-update-a-child-row-a-foreign-key-constraint-fails) i thinks can helps you to verify your data

Comment: Ok so Console.WriteLine(product.Measure.Id); in the foreach loop where i get all products returns the right value for every measure_id for every product, i checked it but the error still occurs.

Comment: ok so your id is a string or a int in the database ? and in your inser ?

Comment: it is int in the MSSQL and in MySQL

Comment: cast your measure id in int32 after insert it or verify that are int32 or int 64 in the two way

Comment: something like that ? CAST(@measure_id AS SIGNED); in the insert query ?

Comment: measure id is int(11) in mysql and just int in MSSQL does this matter? And i tried to make it int(11) but i couldnt do that in MSSQL int just turns to int.

Comment: i don't no sorry. before execute your query display here for watch if all off the data are ok and verify the data in your 2 DB because i think is an error in data in db or in your query

Comment: I just deleted the whole DB schema from MySQL, recreated it and than run the code and now everything runs and imports fine. Maybe the old data was the reason for that error.

Comment: ok fine. I hope heps you anyway